# Why can't I quit the MFC program when I used MsgWaitForMultipleObjects?

Tags: mfc

```cpp
HANDLE g_event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"tasdfasdfsadfasdfasdfas");
BOOL bIsok = TRUE;
while(bIsok)
{
    DWORD dwTime = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &g_event, FALSE, 5000, QS_ALLINPUT);
    MSG msg;
    switch(dwTime)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            switch(msg.message)
            {
            case WM_DESTROY:
            case WM_CLOSE:
            case WM_QUIT:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    break;
    }
}
```

Run this code and then click the close-button. The window hides but the program doesn’t exit.

Why, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Relevant information from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects): *"Functions such as PeekMessage, GetMessage, and WaitMessage mark messages in the queue as old messages. Therefore, after you call one of these functions, a subsequent call to MsgWaitForMultipleObjects will not return **until new input of the specified type arrives**."* Besides that, `bIsok` will always be `TRUE`. Your compiler probably warned you about this.

Comment: Obligatory OldNewThing read: [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects and the queue state](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050217-00/?p=36423/)

Comment: means that I must handle the WM_QUIT by myself，and use suchlike exit(0) to exit current thread?  otherwise, dispatch the WM_QUIT is useless?

Answer (score 1):

The process never terminates, because the `while(bIsok)` loop's predicate never evaluates to `false`. To fix this, the code needs to update the `bIsok` when it's time to shut down. The easiest fix would be to do so in the `WM_QUIT` message handler:

```cpp
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        switch(msg.message)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_CLOSE:
            break;
        case WM_QUIT:
            bIsok = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

While that addresses the immediate issue, there are still more issues with the code, that should be fixed, most notably failure to fully deplete the message queue, when messages arrive. The documentation for [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) contains the following remark:

> `WAIT_OBJECT_0` + *nCount*: New input of the type specified in the `dwWakeMask` parameter is available in the thread's input queue. Functions such as [PeekMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew), [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew), and [WaitMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitmessage) **mark messages in the queue as old messages. Therefore, after you call one of these functions, a subsequent call to MsgWaitForMultipleObjects will not return until new input of the specified type arrives**.

Whenever a message arrives, the code handles only the first message, and then moves on to wait for **new** messages. Instead, the code should process **all** messages before moving on.

Not strictly required, but I would also apply the following changes:

- Remove the timeout from the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. It is not needed and merely causes the thread to wake up repeatedly, even if nothing happened.
- Move the message handling into the window procedure for the toplevel window. [Closing the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/closing-the-window) provides information on the standard procedure: Call `DestroyWindow` in response to `WM_CLOSE`, and `PostQuitMessage` in response to `WM_DESTROY`.

This is the [window procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573.aspx) of the toplevel window:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( uMsg )
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ::DestroyWindow( hwnd );
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
    }
}
```

Updated main loop:

```cpp
HANDLE g_event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"tasdfasdfsadfasdfasdfas");
BOOL bIsok = TRUE;
while(bIsok)
{
    DWORD dwTime = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &g_event, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    switch(dwTime)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
    {
        MSG msg;
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bIsok = false;
            }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    break;
    }
}
```